# Nginx Remove Domain from $host

Tags: nginx

When an HTTP request is sent to my site: mysite.example.com and I set:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host
```

I get mysite.example.com; however all I want is "mysite" I don't want the domain included in the Host header. Is there a way to strip the domain from the host header?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

proxy_set_header Host "mysite";